# In the Statement, "The average size of the shadow cast by any 3D convex shape is $1/4$ times its surface area," how is 'shadow' defined?

Tags: geometry, monte-carlo

I saw this statement the other day in reference to the surface area of a sphere in a 3b1b video, and I have way too much time on my hands so I tried to create a MATLAB program that does a Monte Carlo simulation of a square pyramid (base length = 1, height = 1) and the shadow it would cast if it were randomly rotated.

Just from the math, the surface area  $= \sqrt{5} + 1 \approx 3.236$, so $\frac{1}{4}$ of that $\approx 0.809$.

However, when I run my program the average area of the shadow always comes out to $\approx 0.77$. I did run it a number of times with large sample sizes, so I don't think it's just the case that I have too few samples, and it *always* comes out to 0.76 or 0.77 (almost always (0.77)

I'm thinking that I'm just using the wrong definition of a shadow. I'm imagining a faraway light shining straight down on the pyramid (so parallel rays), so the shadow is just the cross-sectional area of the rotated pyramid in the x-y plane.

Here's the program run twice, where I then find the area of the light blue shaded region. The green shape is three dimensional, but the camera is directly above it, looking directly down and the blue figure is that 2-d cross-section:
(Sorry I don't know how to make the pictures smaller)

[image: First Green]
[image: First Blue]
And the second:
[image: Second Green]
[image: Second Blue]

When I have the computer do this millions of times and then average the area of the light blue shapes, and it comes out to $\approx 0.77$

Am I thinking about the idea of "shadow" wrong? Or why is it off?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you choose a "random rotation" in your Monte Carlo simulation? It's not trivial how to get the "right" probability distribution among all rotations.

Comment: I used a 3d rotation matrix. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix If you go to this link, there's a quick overview it's under rotation in three dimensions and then general rotations. To find alpha, beta, and gamma I used matlab's rand() and did 2*pi*rand() for each. Does that seem like it would work? I used this matrix to rotate each vertex of the pyramid.

Comment: Yeah, choosing each of those angles uniformly (and independently) in $[0,2\pi]$ will not give a uniform distribution of rotations. (For example you could try to keep the rotation generator unchanged, but change how the original pyramid sits in the coordinate system by interchanging some of the axes -- you will probably get different averages).

Comment: What you want instead is something like pick a uniform point on the unit sphere _such that regions of equal area have the same probability of being picked_. One way to do this is to choose $z$ uniformly in $[-1,1]$, chose $\theta$ uniformly in $[0,2\pi]$ and then let your vector be $(\sqrt{1-z^2}\cdot\cos \theta, \sqrt{1-z^2}\cdot\sin \theta, z)$. Then project your shape orthogonally onto a plane that's perpendicular to that vector. (It doesn't matter how you turn the coordinate system _in_ that plane, which is why this procedure has only 2 degrees of freedom).

Comment: I will try that, thank you.

Comment: To project the shape orthogonally onto a plane that's perpendicular to the vector, once I have the vector, could I just find the associated $\alpha$ , $\beta$, and $\gamma$ of the vector and then put that through my rotation matrix and rotate the pyramid so that the tip is in line with vector,  and then take the top-down shadow? Now that I type that out I'm thinking it probably won't work, I might still give it a try as it's pretty easy to do.

Comment: It's easier to supplement the unit vector with two new vectors to make an orthogonal basis (say, with the Gram-Schmidt process, or by taking cross products and normalizing the results), then convert all the coordinates to the new basis and throw away their first (new) coordinates. Then you have the shadow in the yz-plane.

Answer (score 1):

Project it on a plane of a random direction $u$ and get a two dimensional object, calculate its area, and then average over all unit vectors $u$.

To get a random unit vector $u$, you consider $3$ normal independent variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ with distribution $N(0,1)$, $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$, and $u = \frac{X}{\|X\|}$.

Comment: @Troposphere: cf  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html  last method --- i there could be other and better

Comment: Whoops sorry -- for inexplicable reasons I though your $X_i$s were uniformly distributed.

Comment: @Troposphere: Well, it was a bit obscure.  It seems preferable in practice to use distributions on a finite interval like your approach.  I wonder how different methods compare.